# A discrete operator begets even/odd polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, sequences-and-series, partitions, positivity

Given a function $f(x)$ define the forward shift operator by $Ef(x)=f(x+1)$ and the discrete derivative $\delta f(x)=(E-1)f(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$.

Given a partition $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_k)$, where $\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2\geq\dots\geq\lambda_k\geq1$ and $k>0$, define the operator 
$$L_{\lambda}=\frac{(E^{\lambda_1}-1)\cdots(E^{\lambda_k}-1)}{\delta}.$$

Let $(x)_n=x(x-1)\cdots(x-n+1)$ be the falling factorial.

> **Question.**  If $\lambda\vdash n$ then is it true $\Phi_n(x)=L_{\lambda}(x)_n$ is either an even or an odd polynomial, with non-negative integer coefficients? It appears to be so.

**Example.** If $\lambda=(n)$ then $L_{\lambda}(x)_n=\frac{(x+n)_{n+1}-(x)_{n+1}}{n+1}$ indeed satisfies the claim (check!).

Comment: In the definition of $L_\lambda$, do you mean to divide by $\delta^{\lvert\lambda\rvert}$, or really just by $\delta$?

Comment: Just $\delta$. It is not a mistake. Higher powers are not giving the same result.

Comment: Is the numerator of $L_{\lambda}$ a product or a composition?

Comment: It's a composition. Example: $(E^2-1)(E-1)f(x)=(E^3-E^2-E+1)f(x)=f(x+3)-f(x+2)-f(x+1)+f(x)$.

Comment: There is an ambiguity here: The operator $\delta$ is not invertible (in fact, it is not even injective), so how do you divide by $\delta$ ? In light of this, I see two reasonable interpretations of the definition of $L_\lambda$. Interpretation 1 is to redefine $L_\lambda$ as $L_\lambda = \delta' \left(E^{\lambda_1} - 1\right) \cdots \left(E^{\lambda_k} - 1\right)$, where $\delta'$ is the linear operator on $\mathbb{Q}\left[x\right]$ defined as follows: For each polynomial $f$, we let $\delta' f$ be the unique polynomial $g$ **with constant term $0$** satisfying $\delta g = f$. Meanwhile, ...

Comment: ... Interpretation 2 is to understand the fraction in the definition of $L_\lambda$ as being a formal fraction which has to be evaluated as a polynomial in $E$ (using $\delta = E - 1$) before the actual operator $E$ is substituted into it. Thus, $L_\lambda$ is redefined as follows: The polynomial $\left(x^{\lambda_1} - 1\right) \cdots \left(x^{\lambda_k} - 1\right)$ is divisible by $x-1$ as long as $k \geq 1$. Denote the quotient by $q$, and define $L_\lambda$ to be $q\left(E\right)$. These two interpretations both make sense, but they do not ...

Comment: ... give rise to the same $L_\lambda$ (indeed, for any given polynomial $f$, the $L_\lambda f$'s defined using the two interpretations can have different constant terms). Do they nevertheless give rise to the same $L_\lambda \left(x\right)_n$ ? (Your own answer relies on Interpretation 1, as far as I understand it.)

Comment: Ah, I see. The two interpretations do give rise to the same $L_\lambda\left(x\right)_n$, because the $L_\lambda\left(x\right)_n$ computed using Interpretation 2 has constant term $0$. (Why it has constant term $0$ is not completely obvious; it basically comes from observing that $E^k \left(x\right)_n$ has constant term $0$ for all $k \in \left\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}$.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg: I appreciate your meticulous care to help everyone understand the subtle points in the operators actions. Thank you.

Comment: What "$\lambda\vdash n$" means?

Comment: How is this question different from your https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299981?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a proof. I hope someone else can give a more conceptual argument.

Let $\Psi_{\lambda}(x)=L_{\lambda}(x)_n$. We approach the expansion of $\Psi$ differently. Begin with
\begin{align}
\prod_{i=1}^k(E^{\lambda_i}-1)
&=\sum_{T\subset\lambda}(-1)^{k-\#T}E^{\vert T\vert} \\
&=\frac12\left(\sum_{T\subset\lambda}(-1)^{k-\#T}E^{\vert T\vert}+
\sum_{T^c\subset\lambda}(-1)^{k-\#T^c}E^{\vert T^c\vert}\right)\\
&=\frac12\sum_{T\subset\lambda}(-1)^{\#T}\left(
(-1)^kE^{\vert T\vert}+E^{n-\vert T\vert}\right);\end{align}
where $\#T=$ the cardinality of $T$ (if empty then zero), $\vert T\vert=$ sum 
of elements of $T$ and $T^c$ is the complement of $T$ in the set $\lambda$.

The next step uses a couple of key facts, namely:
$$(x+n-q)_{n+1}=(-1)^{n+1}(-x+q)_{n+1} \qquad \text{and} \qquad
\frac1{\delta}(x)_n=\frac{(x)_{n+1}}{n+1}.$$ 
We thus compute
\begin{align}
\Psi_{\lambda}(x)&=\frac1{\delta}\prod_{i=1}^k(E^{\lambda_i}-1)(x)_n\\
&=\frac1{2(n+1)}\sum_{T\subset\lambda}(-1)^{\#T}\left((-1)^k
(x+\vert T\vert)_{n+1}+(x+n-\vert T\vert)_{n+1}\right)\\
&=\frac1{2(n+1)}\sum_{T\subset\lambda}(-1)^{\#T}\left((-1)^k
(x+\vert T\vert)_{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}(-x+\vert T\vert)_{n+1}\right)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{n+k+1}}{2(n+1)}\sum_{T\subset\lambda}(-1)^{\#T}\left((-1)^{n+1}
(x+\vert T\vert)_{n+1}+(-1)^k(-x+\vert T\vert)_{n+1}\right)\\
&=(-1)^{n+k+1}\Psi_{\lambda}(-x).\end{align}
The proof is complete. $\square$

Comment: Note that you seem to understand $\lambda$ as the multiset comprising the numbers $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_k$ here when you write "$T \subset \lambda$". (Just pointing this out, since it confused me.)